# Compare django template varaiable with javascript varaible

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

I am trying to populate a table in django template, but I want to compare cell values, one of them is javascript variable and another is django template variable. Is it possible to compare them without converting django variables to javascript variables? or is there a quick work around?

```
{% for x in price_data %}
<script>
counter++
var VALUE =document.getElementById("price_table").rows[0].cells.item(counter).innerHTML;
</script>

{% if x.room_scan == i and x.checkin == VALUE %}
```

I want to check if x.checkin is equals to VALUE.

Thanks.

Comment: You must do this in JS, not in the Django tag.

Comment: Okay, I thought so. It would solve my problem so much quicker this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Code I used to create the table (as I don't have original table)

```
<table id="price_table">
    <tr>
        {% for x in range %}
            <td>{{ x }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

I passed these variables to view

```
{
    'range': range(1,5),
    'x_room_scan': 2
}
```

and inside the template (I reduced the code a bit to simplify it)

```
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    {% for x in range %}
        counter++;
        var value =document.getElementById("price_table").rows[0].cells.item(counter).innerHTML;
        if({{ x_room_scan }} == value) {
            console.log(value);
        }
    {% endfor %}
</script>
```